# Bluetooth on activity Result

Tags: android, bluetooth

Hi I am working on a project that asks the user to enable Bluetooth and once the user answers yes, it runs another method to connect to an external device. However the code works when Bluetooth is already enable, but it doesn't work when the user has to be asked to enable Bluetooth.

Here is my code:

Check for Bluetooth Status

```
void findBTdevice() throws IOException {


    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null)
    {
        bluetoothStatus = "No bluetooth adapter available";
    }


    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {

    pairBTdevices();

    } else {
        Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);

    }
}
```

On Activity Result

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent Intent) {

    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == 0) {
            bluetoothStatus = "Bluetooth Required";

        } else {
            try {
                pairBTdevices();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Log if that helps

```
D/BluetoothUtils﹕ isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null
W/BluetoothAdapter﹕ getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
D/BluetoothSocket﹕ connect(), SocketState: INIT, mPfd: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[63]}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "it does not work"?

Comment: I mean that it calls the Method and seemingly connects, but the UI gets all messed up

Comment: You get me even more confuse here. What do you mean by "the UI gets all messed up?" Does is suddenly show blinking "Hello World" message all over the places? And what Method get called? the pairBTdevices()?